# Python: printing a tree recursively

Tags: python

I have implemented a REST API and this returns the following information:

```
Parent/SiteA
Parent/SiteB
Parent/SiteC
Parent/SiteD
Parent/SiteD/xyz
Parent/SiteE
Parent/SiteD/xyz/Site8
Parent/SiteE/def
Parent/SiteF/Site3
Parent/SiteF
Parent/SiteF/Site4
Parent/SiteF/Site5
```

I would like to print is as follows (a tree structure):

```
Parent
   SiteA
   SiteB
   SiteC
   SiteD 
      xyz
         Site8
   SiteE
      def
   SiteF  
      Site3
      Site4
      Site5
```

There can be unlimited amount of sites under a parent site so some form of recursion would be required.

I really have no clue on a potential solution, tried so many things, lost so much time but can't seem to find a solution. Anyone willing to provide a hint?

Comment: Once you split upon "/" any of those paths, you get a number of tabs that you could prepend the element of the line.

Comment: can you group in a list or something? how do you get those strings?

Comment: These strings are returned like that from a REST API response. I just need to parse these strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per sal's comment, if you already have the list of paths, this is easy and does not require recursion:

```
>>> info = [
...     "Parent/SiteA",
...     "Parent/SiteB",
...     "Parent/SiteC",
...     "Parent/SiteD",
...     "Parent/SiteD/xyz",
...     "Parent/SiteE",
...     "Parent/SiteD/xyz/Site8",
...     "Parent/SiteE/def",
...     "Parent/SiteF/Site3",
...     "Parent/SiteF",
...     "Parent/SiteF/Site4",
...     "Parent/SiteF/Site5",
... ]
>>>
>>> info.sort()
>>> for line in info:
...     print('   '*line.count('/') + line.split('/')[-1])
...
   SiteA
   SiteB
   SiteC
   SiteD
      xyz
         Site8
   SiteE
      def
   SiteF
      Site3
      Site4
      Site5
```

To break down that `print` statement a bit:

- `line.count('/')` is the number of `/` characters.
- `line.split('/')` splits the string into a list, e.g. `['Parent', 'SiteF']`.
- You can multiple a string by an int.  `'   ' * 2 == '      '`.
- `[-1]` selects the last element of a list.
- You can add two strings together with `+`.  `'foo' + 'bar' == 'foobar'`.

(edit) I noticed in reviewing your original question that the input you start with doesn't actually include an entry for `Parent` on its own, but you want it to appear in the output.  Of course it's easy to just grab the single top-level root folder on its own and add it in there, but what if there were other holes in the data at arbitrarily deep levels of the tree?  So I had some fun adding a set comprehension that'll go over the list of paths and "fill in" any missing parent folders by extracting their names from the children.

```
for path in sorted(list(
    {
        '/'.join(path.split('/')[:i])
        for i in range(1, len(path.split('/')))
        for path in info
    } | set(info)
)):
    print('   ' * path.count('/') + path.split('/')[-1])
```

Have fun!  ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's not fully working, see Site8 which should be under SiteD, not under siteE

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that the input wasn't already sorted.  Easy fix!

Comment: Thanks Sam. You mind giving some more explanation on that print line. Even seeing what you did makes me realize I would not have found it, hence maybe some more explanation would me (and others) help understand. :-)

Comment: Added some explanation at the end of the various operations that go into that print statement.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, if you split each line by the divider, you get a count that increases with depth of the path. Use that number to repeat a "spacer" character, and then print the result.

```
sites = ['Parent/SiteA',
'Parent/SiteB',
'Parent/SiteC',
'Parent/SiteD',
'Parent/SiteD/xyz',
'Parent/SiteE',
'Parent/SiteD/xyz/Site8',
'Parent/SiteE/def',
'Parent/SiteF/Site3',
'Parent/SiteF',
'Parent/SiteF/Site4',
'Parent/SiteF/Site5']


spacer = ' '                                 # use whatever you need for spacer
for site in sorted(sites):
    prepend = len(line.split('/')) * spacer  # count how many items, and repeat the spacer
    item = line.split('/')[-1]               # the item we want to display is the last one
    print(prepend, item)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not fully working, see Site8 which should be under SiteD, not under siteE

Comment: Yup, adding a `sorted` statement would fix that.